# Check_mk_agent Error: Failed to gather SQL Server instances

Tags: sql-server, monitoring, nagios, check-mk

I am using Check_mk monitoring. I would like to monitor my SQL Server performance counters.

I have placed `mssql.vbs` plugin in the `Check_mk` agent plugin folder and then restarted the `Check_mk_agent` service.

Post that, I have performed the discovery in `Check_mk` server.

By doing everything listed above, I am not able to see any performance counters in `Check_mk` server.

I have also run the `Check_mk_agent.exe` on the command prompt, it is showing error:

> Failed to gather SQL Server instances

No luck. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You should discuss this with Mathias-Kettner (the publisher of the Check_MK tool set).

Comment: How to connect with him? Any source.

Comment: No idea.  Check the documentation that came with the tool.

Comment: I have tried contacting Mathias-Kettner but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

I have used the check_mk_agent 1.2.8p13 Core.

You can find the agent on below URL:
https://mathias-kettner.de/check_mk_download_source.html

Install the check_mk_agent.msi and put the mssql.vbs plugin in the plugin folder.

Go to your command prompt and try:
C:\Program Files (x86)\check_mk\check_mk_agent.exe test